# Anyone seen a "honeypot" suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

According to meta.SO ([ref.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159544/why-no-honeypot-suggested-edits)), a network-wide roll-out of *honeypot* edits has been implemented.  Essentially, some rubbish edits (that appear superficially okay) are added to the suggested edit queue, and if they are deemed suitable, it is noted on that user's account.

> **Question**: Has anyone seen a "honeypot" suggested edit?

Comment: The stackexchange format is great for many things. Humor isn't really one of them.

Comment: I really like the SE sense of humour!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one: [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

The answer to this question until today was "no, not on math.SE."

The reason it changed is at [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10740/do-we-want-to-enable-the-review-auditing-feature-that-discourages-robo-reviewing?lq=1).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it seems I got one too.  This one was rather blatant though:

[image: Honeypot edit]

Comment: Actually, its a first post, and not a suggested edit.

Answer (score 2):

Another first post (and not a suggested edit) but this time it's a high quality post (and not a low-quality post like Douglas Stones's).

[image: Honey pot high quality first post]

Comment: Wow, that question looks interesting too (with 12 up-votes!).